# Run iis on docker container

Tags: docker, iis

I want to call iis from my docker. so as you can see i have these images:

```
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
microsoft/iis                          latest              bb59d00aa26a        3 weeks ago         4.61GB
mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore   ltsc2019            954d1507112f        3 weeks ago         4.43GB
```

So i call this to run windows core :

```
docker run -i -t 954d1507112f
```

It works and i the cmd is opened ,i want to install IIS on my container so i run this :

```
Add-WindowsFeature web-server, web-webserver
```

but i get this error :

```
'Add-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Please read Server Core specific documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should run `powershell` command in docker container and use `Add-WindowsFeature web-server, web-webserver` in the `ps`

Comment: Yes, like this: RUN C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -c Add-WindowsFeature web-server,web-webserver